# PHP - Cannot use Heredoc within a class method?

Tags: php, heredoc

I'm writing the code for a controller method and I need to use it to send an email.  I'm trying to use heredoc syntax to fill in the email body, however, the closing tag doesn't seem to be recognized.

```
$this->email = new Email(); 
$this->email->from = 'Automated Email';
$this->email->to = 'me@myemail.com';
$this->email->subject = 'A new user has registered';
$this->email->body = <<<EOF

Hello, a new user has registered.

EOF;

$this->email->send();
```

Everything from the opening `<<< EOF` down (till the end of the file) is displayed as if it was in quotes.

Can anyone see why this is not working?

Any advice appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: What version of PHP are you using?

Comment: You had whitespace after `EOF;` - the ending identifier for heredoc strings must be completely isolated on it's own line, with no leading or trailing whitespace; see the big red warning here: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Check that you don't have any whitepace after the semicolon after "EOF".

Comment: +1 nice catch. Highlighting the code reveals the bogus whitespace.